# Intl.NumberFormat String Currency before number

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, currency, intl

The following string return the value like: 938.173,00 euro. How to obtain the value like: Euro 938.173,00?

```
formattedValue = value.toLocaleString('it-IT', {currency: 'EUR', currencyDisplay: 'name', style: 'currency'});
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome. Why [tag:google-apps-script] was included? If you are using Google Apps Script pleas clarify if this is being used on the server side or on the cliente side. Also add a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any specific options in `Intl` to custom-prepend the currency. It is done automatically according to your locale. But, you could simply [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
const value = 938173.00
const formattedValue = `euro ${value.toLocaleString('it-IT', {currency: 'EUR', currencyDisplay: 'name', style: 'currency'}).replace(" euro","")}`;
console.info(formattedValue);
```

Comment: Perfect! Works :)