# Convert number to currency in apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, types, number-formatting

I'm wanting to convert a specific range of numbers to currency. I'm not sure if such formatting exists in google apps script. I notice that when defining one cell value with a "$", it automatically declares any other numbers in that range with a "$". So I assume that there is some kind of currency type.

If so, is there some type of fancy method to convert a number to this currency format or am I to simply convert each number to a string and add a "$" in front of each one.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the difference between [the number format of the cell](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) and your goal of `some type of fancy method to convert a number to this currency format`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: My bad, as Ruben described because apps script is just javascript, I should have assumed their isn't a currency format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Apps Script uses JavaScript, as the later doesn't have a currency data type, Google Apps Script either. The V8 engine (default for new project) supports Internationalization API, through the [Intl object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl), but the old engine (Rhino) doesn't.

If your project is using the default settings, you might use [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) (examples taken from MDN)

```
const number = 123456.789;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(number));
// expected output: "123.456,79 €"

// the Japanese yen doesn't use a minor unit
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('ja-JP', { style: 'currency', currency: 'JPY' }).format(number));
// expected output: "￥123,457"
```

It's worthy to note that Google Sheets stores "currency" values as numbers. The "$" is added by the automatic number formatting feature. If you want that your script adds this formatting use `setNumberFormat`.

Related

- [How to format numbers as currency strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/149055/1595451)
- [Set cell format with google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38490800/1595451)
- [Intl.NumberFormat String Currency before number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60252554/1595451)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a built-in Javascript functionality like this:

```
var numberToCurrency = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'});

numberToCurrency.format(3600);
```

Comment: Intl only works in projects using the default runtime engine (V8)